# Angular8: BehaviourSubject partially not working when extracting to another Service

Tags: angular, angular8, behaviorsubject

I encountered a really strange issue: in my application I followed the principle of having a state service handling all states. As the app is growing, I decided to create sub-state services. I extracted all related functions to a dedicatet service. Among others, this part was moved from **state.service.ts** to **bubble03-state.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Bubble03StateService {

  constructor() { }

  /* tslint:disable:rule1 member-ordering */ 

  // ...

  public currentVisibleEFSubcontainer$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private currentSubjectValue = '';
  updateCurrentVisibleEFSubcontainer(newVisibleContainer: string): void {
    console.log(`updating with value ${newVisibleContainer}`);
    if (newVisibleContainer !== this.currentSubjectValue) {
      this.currentVisibleEFSubcontainer$.next(newVisibleContainer);
      this.currentSubjectValue = newVisibleContainer;
    } else {
      this.currentVisibleEFSubcontainer$.next('');
      this.currentSubjectValue = '';
    }
  }

}
```

The method `updateCurrentVisibleEFSubcontainer()` is called from two locations, one is a component, one is another service. Now the strange part: as soon as I moved this code to the new sub-state service, only one call triggers the subscriptions, while the other call does not. I can't really explain why, since its the exact same code, just in another place. All other moved functions work just fine. Following the two calls:

**in a component**

```
onClickRowElement(): void {
  if (this.rowElementAmount > 0) {
    this.bubble03State.updateCurrentVisibleEFSubcontainer(this.rowElementTitle);
    this.rowElementClicked.emit(this.rowElementTitle);
  }
}
```

**in another service**

```
chart.options.data[0].click = (e) => {
  this.explodePie(e);
  this.bubble03State.updateCurrentVisibleEFSubcontainer(e.dataPoint.name);
};
```

**the subscription**

```
this.bubble03State.currentVisibleEFSubcontainer$.subscribe(
  newVisibleEFContainer => {
    this.handleExpandableSubContainer(newVisibleEFContainer);
    console.log(`newly visible ${newVisibleEFContainer}`);
  }
);
```

If the method is called a few times from the component, following output gets logged

```
> updating with value Kontoführung 
> newly visible Kontoführung updating
> with value Versand & Bearbeitung 
> newly visible Versand & Bearbeitung
> updating with value Versand & Bearbeitung 
> newly visible
```

However, calling the methods from the service results in following log

```
> updating with value Kontoführung
> updating with value Versand & Bearbeitung
> updating with value Buchungsgebühren
```

As soon as I put the method and its corresponding BehaviourSubject back into the main service, everything works as intended. What could possibly cause this behaviour? There is no difference between the state services, except the name. Both are provided in root.

**EDIT:**

For clarification, the initial situation when posting the question was following:

- The `StateService` was located in the `CoreModule` and provided in `root`. The `CoreModule` is only imported in the `AppModule`.
- The `Bubble03StateService` was located in a lazy loaded Module and also provided in `root`.
- The `Bubble03StateService` is used in the lazy loaded module and in a third service, which is also located in the `CoreModule` and provided in `root`, while the `StateService` is used in every module.

Following Richard Dunn's suggestion, I relocated the `Bubble03StateService` and tried a few things. It is now located in the `CoreModule` too.

- When I remove the `provideIn: 'root'` and put both services in the `providers`-Array of the `AppModule`, the regular `StateService` still works fine, but the `Bubble03StateService` throws an `NullInjectorError: no providers for...`
- Reinserting the `provideIn: 'root'` and removing from `AppModule`, the services are loaded, but something happens I do not understand: In the constructor of the services, I create a random number and log it whenever calling a function of the services. When putting the `BehaviourSubject` and its corresponding update method in the `StateService`, the random number is always the same, no matter who calls the method (third Service and lazy loaded component). But when I put it back in the `Bubble03StateService` (which at this point is in all ways identical to the `StateService`, except its name), the random number is different when called from the third Service and from the lazy loaded component. This confuses me even more, since now all three services from `CoreModule` should be singletons. If not, why is the `StateService` a singleton and the `Bubble03StateService` not, when they are declared, provided and located in the same way?

Comment: I can't spot the issue, are you getting any errors? Have you verified that `chart.options.data[0].click` is in fact getting called? Just to note: spacing makes it much easier to read your code. Also, BehaviourSubjects expose their current value by calling their `.value()` method.

Comment: @RichardDunn yes, the method is in fact called, otherwise the log from the service would not be visible (and furthermore it is in context of a chart-object, which gets also manipulated on click). There are no errors, it just seems that the next()-method called from the service does not trigger the subscriptions. Thanks for the feedback regarding spaces, I presume you refer to the clustered subject, method and if-statement in the service?

Comment: I see, I misinterpreted the logs. How is the 'other' service importing the 'data' service? In other words, how is dependency injection managed. Your refactoring may have caused the component and 'other' service to have two different instances of the data service, thus the data service is logging the new event, but your other service is subscribed to a different instance that isn't getting the event. I don't think this is likely to be the issue, but it is possible.

Comment: My last comment may be more likely than I thought, with Angular 8's lazy loading configuration enabled by default, it may be creating singleton services for you by using the `providedIn: 'root'` method of dependency injection. You should change this to the other method by using: `@NgModule({ providers: [Bubble03StateService] })` in your root module. This will guarantee it's a singleton service.

Comment: I think that should be the problem. I didn't stated that the module, in which this second sub-state service is defined, is indeed lazy loaded. Will try it later and give you feedback, feel free to then to write and answer so I can mark it as solved!

Comment: Cool, hopefully that's all it is. Let me know if it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause for the issue.

Somehow, while auto-importing the service inside the other service, the auto-import function added the extension `.js` to the import statement. This is really hard to catch, since it is not a thing you'll usually check explicitly.

While there isn't even a `.js` File in this location, Angular somehow understands this and imports the right class / service / component etc from the `.ts`-File. BUT it creates a new instance of the service, annihilating the principle of singletons.

So in the end, removing the `.js` extension from the import was all that had to be done.

Comment: The stuff of nightmares. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Angular 8's lazy loading of modules is causing the issue. Specifically, it may be creating singleton services if you are using the `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` method of dependency injection, depending on the subscribers parent module's relationship with the root module.

You should remove this method and use: `@NgModule({ providers: [Bubble03StateService] })` in your root module instead. This will guarantee it's a singleton service.

Comment: I updated my question after trying your suggestions, unfortunately I still have an issue.

Comment: I've pondered it a bit, but can't think what might be wrong. I've used RxJS a lot, with Angular, Node and React, and I've never seen this issue before, so I reckon it must be Angular's DI. Perhaps it's not the Service being lazy loaded, but instead the Component, that's causing the issue?

Comment: yes, the component with the method `onClickRowElement()` is lazy loaded, but not the `CoreModule` now containing all three services.

Comment: I think I found the cause, yet not an explanation. It seems that - altough provided in root - if this service gets injected in another service, it is not a singleton anymore.

Comment: check my answer, in the end, the cause was very trivial